# How to remove an element from a doubly-nested array in a MongoDB document

Tags: mongodb

I have a document structure something along the lines of the following:

```js
{
"_id" : "777",
"someKey" : "someValue",
"someArray" : [
    {
        "name" : "name1",
        "someNestedArray" : [
            {
                "name" : "value"
            },
            {
                "name" : "delete me"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to delete the nested array element with the value "delete me".

I know I can find documents which match this description using nested `$elemMatch` expressions. What is the query syntax for removing the element in question?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

To delete the item in question you're actually going to use an update. More specifically you're going to do an update with the `$pull` command which will remove the item from the array.

```js
db.temp.update(
  { _id : "777" },
  {$pull : {"someArray.0.someNestedArray" : {"name":"delete me"}}}
)
```

There's a little bit of "magic" happening here. Using `.0` indicates that we know that we are modifying the 0th item of `someArray`. Using `{"name":"delete me"}` indicates that we know the exact data that we plan to remove.

This process works just fine if you load the data into a client and then perform the update. This process works less well if you want to do "generic" queries that perform these operations.

I think it's easiest to simply recognize that updating arrays of sub-documents generally requires that you have the original in memory at some point.

---

In response to the first comment below, you can probably help your situation by changing the data structure a little

```js
"someObjects" : {
  "name1":  {
        "someNestedArray" : [
            {
                "name" : "value"
            },
            {
                "name" : "delete me"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now you can do `{$pull : { "someObjects.name1.someNestedArray" : ...`

Here's the problem with your structure. MongoDB does not have very good support for manipulating "sub-arrays". Your structure has an array of objects and those objects contain arrays of more objects.

If you have the following structure, you are going to have a difficult time using things like `$pull`:

```js
array [
  { subarray : array [] },
  { subarray : array [] },
]
```

If your structure looks like that *and* you want to update `subarray` you have two options:

1. Change your structure so that you can leverage `$pull`.
2. Don't use `$pull`. Load the entire object into a client and use `findAndModify`.

Comment: What if we do not know the index of the item in someArray?  I should have specified that condition in my original question, my apologies.

Comment: The way you specified someObjects.name1 does not seem to work?

Comment: I am strugling with this issue. MongoDB does not support 2nd level deep `$` [positional operator] for find and update.

Comment: @UdayHiwarale For two-level deep, you can just use `{_id: 777, someArray.name: "name1"}, {$pull: {"someArray.$.someNestedArray": {"name": "delete me"}}}`. But if you have deeper nested arrays it won't work because MongoDB only supports one `$`. Multi `$` support may be available in version 2.9, according to the official developers.

Answer (score 38):

MongoDB 3.6 added [`$[]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) operator that facilitates updates to arrays that contain embedded documents. So the problem can be solved by:

```
db.test.update(
  { _id : "777" },
  {$pull : {"someArray.$[].someNestedArray" : {"name":"delete me"}}}
)
```

Answer (score 14):

As @Melkor has commented (should probably be an answer as itself),

If you do not know the index use:

```
{
    _id: TheMainID, 
    "theArray._id": TheArrayID
},
{
    $pull: {
        "theArray.$.theNestedArray": {
            _id: theNestedArrayID
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

From MongoDB 3.6 on you can use `arrayFilters` to do this:

```
db.test.update(
  { _id: "777" }, 
  { $pull: { "someArray.$[elem].someNestedArray": { name: "delete me" } } },
  { arrayFilters: [{ "elem.name": "name1"}] }
)
```

see also https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/index.html#update-all-documents-that-match-arrayfilters-in-an-array

Answer (score 4):

Other example and usage  could be like this:

```
{

    "company": {
        "location": {
            "postalCode": "12345",
            "Address": "Address1",
            "city": "Frankfurt",
            "state": "Hessen",
            "country": "Germany"
        },
        "establishmentDate": "2019-04-29T14:12:37.206Z",
        "companyId": "1",
        "ceo": "XYZ"
    },
    "items": [{
            "name": "itemA",
            "unit": "kg",
            "price": "10"
        },
        {
            "name": "itemB",
            "unit": "ltr",
            "price": "20"
        }

    ]
}
```

1. DELETE : Mongodb Query to delete ItemB:

```
db.getCollection('test').update(   
    {"company.companyId":"1","company.location.city":"Frankfurt"},
    {$pull : {"items" : {"name":"itemB"}}}
)
```

2. FIND: Find query for itemB:

```
db.getCollection('test').find(
    {"company.companyId":"1","company.location.city":"Frankfurt","items.name":"itemB"},
    { "items.$": 1 }
)
```

3.UPDATE : update query for itemB:

```
db.getCollection('test').update
(
 {"company.companyId":"1","company.location.city":"Frankfurt","items.name":"itemB"},
 { $set: { "items.$[].price" : 90 }}, 
   { multi: true });
```

Comment: If possible you should use that fewer queries as possible... But It is one of the safest way.