# deleting content from a particular collection

Tags: json, mongodb

I have a JSON document like

```
{
"branch": [
    {
        "section": [
            {
                "sub": "edc",
                "time": "one hour",
                "frequency": "3"
            },
            {
                "sub": "bee",
                "time": "two hours",
                "frequency": "4"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "section": [
            {
                "sub": "ss",
                "time": "one hour",
                "frequency": "2"
            },
            {
                "sub": "ms",
                "time": "two hours",
                "frequency": "5"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Now I want to delete

```
{
  "sub": "edc",
  "time": "one hour",
  "frequency": "3"
}
```

using `"sub":"edc"` from the following collection

I want the query to perform changes in mongo db

Comment: Is `branch` the collection containing `section` documents?

Comment: "branch" is not a collection. The above json document is in the collection say "college" in mongo db. I want to update the database where I could remove  {
  "sub": "edc",
  "time": "one hour",
  "frequency": "3"
} the following

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$pull`, although i've not done it with nested array.

See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/pull/

Something like: (but you'll need to test it)

```
db.yourcoll.update( { "branch.section.sub": 'edu' }, { $pull: { "branch.section.sub": 'edu' } } )
```

This is a similar question:

[How to remove an element from a doubly-nested array in a MongoDB document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228210/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-doubly-nested-array-in-a-mongodb-document)