# MongoDB (java) - Delete item in a double nested field

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to make a function 
**deleteEmployee(String companyName, String departmentName, String employeeName);**

Its job is to delete an *employee* item of the *employees* list inside a *departments* array which is inside a *company* entry. The structure of the BSON is as follows :

```
{ 
    "name" : "company1" , 
    "departments" : [ 
        { 
            "name" : "science" , 
            "employees" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "alex"
                } , 
                {   
                    "name" : "john"
                } 
            ]
        } , 
        { 
            "name" : "arts" , 
            "employees" : [ 
                { 
                    "name" : "bob"
                } , 
                { 
                    "name" : "david"
                } 
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How is that possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228210/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-doubly-nested-array-in-a-mongodb-document

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you able to write the query that deletes the employee item without using java driver first?

Comment: I managed the deletion using a department index in  "departments" array.
You can check my solution here :(https://github.com/medmelki/peopledirectory/blob/master/src/main/java/org/kapit/peopledirectory/dao/impl/CompanyDAOImpl.java#L90) but really isn't  a good one.