# pull from mongo nested array

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, aggregate

```
{
    "partners" : [
        {
            "partnerId" : 5,
            "topicIds" : [
                "59de26f2e4b0f263704769e5"
            ]
        },
        {
            "partnerId" : 45,
            "topicIds" : [
                "alpha",
                "beta"
            ]
        },
        {
            "partnerId" : 12345,
            "topicIds" : [
                "alpha"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to pull certain topicIds from specified partners.
So for example I want to pull **alpha** topic from partnerId = 45 (the entry should remain with topicIds = ["beta"]).

I tried:

```
db.mypartnercoll.update({}, {$pull:{"partners":{"partnerId":45, "topicIds":{"$in":["alpha"]}}}})
```

however this removes the entire partnerId = 45 entry. I will have a single partnerId value and multiple topicIds to pull.

Comment: Try `{$pull:{"partners.topicIds":{"partnerId":45, "topicIds":{"$in":["alpha"]}}}}`

Comment: ```WriteResult({
 "nMatched" : 0,
 "nUpserted" : 0,
 "nModified" : 0,
 "writeError" : {
  "code" : 16837,
  "errmsg" : "cannot use the part (partners of partners.topicIds) to traverse the element ({partners: [ { partnerId: 5.0, topicIds: [ \"59de26f2e4b0f263704769e5\" ] }, { partnerId: 45.0, topicIds: [ \"alpha\", \"beta\" ] }, { partnerId: 12345.0, topicIds: [ \"alpha\" ] } ]})"
 }
})```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228210/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-doubly-nested-array-in-a-mongodb-document Specially, the last answer

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
db.mypartnercoll.update({}, {$pull:{"partners":{"partnerId":45, "topicIds":{"$in":["alpha"]}}}})
```

use

```
db.mypartnercoll.update({"partners.$.partnerId":"yourdesired_partnerId"}, 
{$pull:{"partners":{"partnerId":45, "topicIds":{"$in":["alpha"]}}}})
```

this is an update query so you can specify in the first {} a certain document or array element to operate on