# Update all objects in a MongoDB document array field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**What I'm trying to do**

I am trying to update all objects inside a field array in a MongoDB document using mongoose.

**What I have**

User document

```
{
 id: <ObjectId>,
 ...
 notifications: [
  {
   commissionId: <ObjectId>
   commissioner: <ObjectId>
   date: ...
   description: "You have a new commission!"
  },
  {
   commissionId: <ObjectId>
   commissioner: <ObjectId>
   date: ...
   description: "You have a new commission!"
  },
 ]
}
```

**What I want to have**

```
{
 id: <ObjectId>,
 ...
 notifications: [
  {
   commissionId: <ObjectId>
   commissioner: <ObjectId>
   date: ...
   description: "You have a new commission!"
   read: true // Add read field with a value of true
  },
  {
   commissionId: <ObjectId>
   commissioner: <ObjectId>
   date: ...
   description: "You have a new commission!"
   read: true // Add read field with a value of true
  },
 ]
}
```

I am working with mongoose which right now I am using the `findByIdandUpdate` method. I tried
using a method to do this but it just failed.

```
await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        args.userId,
        {
          notifRead: true,
          $set: {
            "notifications.$.read": true, // FAIL "The positional operator did not find the match needed 
                                          // from the query."
          },
        },
        {
          new: true,
          runValidators: true,
        }
      );
```

Is there a way to do this simply?

Comment: You can use $[] operator to do that. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57622658/11711316

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be possible using `all positional operator $[]`, you can do this:

```
await User.update(
        args.userId,
        {
          $set: {
            "notifications.$[].read": true,                             
          },
        },
        {
          muti: true
        }
      );
```

For more details, you can check [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/).