# Mongoose pull only single string in array inside array

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I have the below document in mongoose. And I want to pull only strings instead of delete objects.

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6051e87aa8698c13fb4951fa"
  },
  "user": {
    "$oid": "6051e87aa8698c13fb4951f7"
  },
  "channelDetail": [
    {
      "hiddenchannels": [],
      "thingchannels": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6051e87aa8698c13fb4951fb"
      },
      "room": {
        "$oid": "6051e87aa8698c13fb4951f9"
      }
    },
    {
      "room": {
        "$oid": "60a8e3f685b8741eaef56e25"
      },
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60e03c7076b5d3915dad1c3b"
      },
      "thingchannels": [
        {
          "$oid": "60e0158af5f1cf131bbb7be6"
        },
        {
          "$oid": "60e0158af5f1cf131bbb7be7"
        },
        {
          "$oid": "60e0158af5f1cf131bbb7be8"
        },
        {
          "$oid": "60e0158af5f1cf131bbb7be9"
        }
      ],
      "hiddenchannels": []
    },
    {
      "hiddenchannels": [],
      "thingchannels": [],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60e02c651b08eb18ac565770"
      },
      "room": {
        "$oid": "60e02c5c1b08eb18ac56576f"
      }
    }
  ],
  "__v": 13,
  "localUpdateAt": 1625306846846
}]
```

Now I want to delete a single string in `thingchannels` array, but the query returns the full object instead of delete string.

```
await this.roomUserDetail.updateMany(
        { "channelDetail.thingchannels": { $in: ["60e0158af5f1cf131bbb7be6"] } },
        {
          $pull: {
            channelDetail: {
              thingchannels: { $in: ["60e0158af5f1cf131bbb7be6"] },
            },
          },
        }
      );
```

Is there any way to delete only a string inside the string array?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228210/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-doubly-nested-array-in-a-mongodb-document/57622658#57622658

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc does not work because I have * thingchannels* is object Array. so $pull not accept.
Please see error https://ibb.co/fGVYxXT

Comment: Which mongoose version do you use? Can you update it to lastest version?

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc "version": "4.4.1"

Comment: If so it's not compatible with that solution. Cam you update mongoose and mongodb?

Comment: this version latest one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234472/discussion-between-cuong-le-ngoc-and-nalawala-murtuza).

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc Problem resolve. thank for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following, I also tried it, working fine.

```
await this.roomUserDetail.updateMany({ 
  "channelDetail.thingchannels": { 
    $in: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId("60e0158af5f1cf131bbb7be6")] 
  } 
},{
  $pull:{
    "channelDetail.$[].thingchannels":{
      $in:[mongoose.Types.ObjectId("60e0158af5f1cf131bbb7be6")]
    }
  }
})
```

OUTPUT after query run:

```
{
    "user": {
        "$oid": "6051e87aa8698c13fb4951f7"
    },
    "channelDetail": [{
        "hiddenchannels": [],
        "thingchannels": [],
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "6051e87aa8698c13fb4951fb"
        },
        "room": {
            "$oid": "6051e87aa8698c13fb4951f9"
        }
    }, {
        "room": {
            "$oid": "60a8e3f685b8741eaef56e25"
        },
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "60e03c7076b5d3915dad1c3b"
        },
        "thingchannels": [{
            "$oid": "60e0158af5f1cf131bbb7be7"
        }, {
            "$oid": "60e0158af5f1cf131bbb7be8"
        }, {
            "$oid": "60e0158af5f1cf131bbb7be9"
        }],
        "hiddenchannels": []
    }, {
        "hiddenchannels": [],
        "thingchannels": [],
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "60e02c651b08eb18ac565770"
        },
        "room": {
            "$oid": "60e02c5c1b08eb18ac56576f"
        }
    }],
    "__v": 13,
    "localUpdateAt": 1625306846846
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update monggoes 5.13 and do belove code.

```
"channelDetail.$[].thingchannels": { $in: ["x","y"]},
```